# WITH_OBJECT_HEADERS enabled GC from Dalvik?

Tags: android, garbage-collection, virtual-machine, dalvik

As I know Dalvik VM does not support generational GC as default.

But, I found "`WITH_OBJECT_HEADERS`" compilation flag which could be related with generational GC from `HeapInternal.h` file.

```
typedef struct DvmHeapChunk {
#if WITH_OBJECT_HEADERS
    u4 header;
    const Object *parent;
    const Object *parentOld;
    const Object *markFinger;
    const Object *markFingerOld;
    u2 birthGeneration;
    u2 markCount;
    u2 scanCount;
    u2 oldMarkGeneration;
    u2 markGeneration;
    u2 oldScanGeneration;
    u2 scanGeneration;
#endif
```

Does anyone try to build Dalvik with this option enabled? Do you know anything about generational GC support from Dalvik?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was part of an experiment.  There is no generational GC support in the current release.  Improvements to the GC will be part of a future release.

Comment: As I see from Google IO 2010 session, I believe Android Froyo still does not support generational GC.